# GitServlet Password query after push command

Tags: embedded-jetty, jgit

I want to clone and modify a repository using jgit. 
I want to use the HTTP protocol. 
For this, jgit offers a servlet (GitServlet). 
I use a servlet container Jetty to run the servlet GitServlet. 
I have implemented this as follows:

```
public class HttpGitConnection {

    public void start() {
       Server server = new Server(this.port);
       GitServlet gs = new GitServlet();
       gs.setRepositoryResolver(this::handler);
       ServletHandler servletHandler = new ServletHandler();
       servletHandler.addServletWithMapping(new ServletHolder(gs), "/configs/*");
       this.server.setHandler(servletHandler);
       server.start();
       server.join();
    }

    private Repository handler(HttpServletRequest request, String name){
       try {
           Logger.debug("Repository Request {}", name);
           if (name.contains(".git")) {
               String repoName = name.split(".git")[0];
               if (!new File(repoFolder + File.separator + repoName).exists()) {
                  throw new RepositoryNotFoundException(name);
               }
               Repository repository;
               if (repositories.containsKey(repoName)) {
                   Logger.debug("GET REPO");
                   repository = repositories.get(repoName);
               } else {
                   Logger.debug("Open GIT REPO!");
                   repository = Git.open(new File(repoFolder + File.separator + repoName)).getRepository();
                   this.repositories.put(repoName, repository);
               }
               repository.incrementOpen();
               return repository;
            } else {
               Logger.error("Invalid repository name {}", name);
               throw new Exception("Invalid repository name " + name);
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
         }
    }

}
```

I start the application and execute the following commands:

```
git clone http://localhost:8080/configs/MyService.git
Cloning into 'MyService'...
...
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

if I make a change and execute a push, then a password request comes up:

```
git push
Username for 'http://localhost:8080':
```

Where does this query come from? Does the query come from the Jetty or does it come from jGit? If it comes from the Jetty, what username is needed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user query came from the GitServlet/JGit. At first, the http connection has to be activated, so the configuration of the Git can easily be done as follows:

```
StoredConfig config = repository.getConfig();
config.setBoolean("http", null, "receivepack", true);
config.save();
```

Now the changes in the repository can be pushed. I found the solution on the following page: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=arquillian/smart-testing/smart-testing-master/functional-tests/git-rules/src/main/java/org/arquillian/smart/testing/rules/git/server/EmbeddedHttpGitServer.java